# XML filtering based on value of a field using Groovy Script

Tags: groovy

I have below XML to filter based on the value of custom_string14 field under job_information segment, I have to filter the CompoundEmployee segments from xml based on the values present in an array [MW_9X, MW_9R]. If I find the value of custom_string14 not present in the array, i need to ignore that CompoundEmployee. As shown below job_information segment can occur multiple times

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
    <CompoundEmployee>
        <id>970</id>
        <person>
            <birth_name>Name1</birth_name>
            <employment_information>
                <job_information>
                    <custom_string13>MD_6_DAY</custom_string13>
                    <custom_string14>MW_9X</custom_string14>
                </job_information>
                <job_information>
                    <custom_string13>MD_6_DAY</custom_string13>
                    <custom_string14>MW_9S</custom_string14>
                </job_information>
            </employment_information>
        </person>
    </CompoundEmployee>
    <CompoundEmployee>
        <id>130</id>
        <person>
            <birth_name>Name2</birth_name>
            <employment_information>
                <job_information>
                    <custom_string13>MD_6_DAY</custom_string13>
                    <custom_string14>MW_9R</custom_string14>
                </job_information>
                <job_information>
                    <custom_string13>MD_6_DAY</custom_string13>
                    <custom_string14>MW_9R</custom_string14>
                </job_information>
            </employment_information>
        </person>
    </CompoundEmployee>
</queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
```

I tried with below Groovy script and i am not able to capture all **item** in one node. Please help with below script as I am new to Groovy and stuck with this issue

```
import groovy.xml.*;

def body = """//Add Above XML here//"""

def array = ["MW_9X", "MW_9R"]
def list = new XmlParser().parseText(body)
def flag = true
def filtered = []

for(item in list)
{
    def companyRules = item.'**'.custom_string14.toArray()
    for(ech in companyRules)
    {
        println ech.text()
        if(!array.contains(ech.text()))
        {
            flag = false
        }
    }
    if(flag)
    {
        filtered = filtered + item
    }
    else
    {
        flag = true
    }
}
filtered = filtered.toString()
def selected = XmlUtil.serialize(filtered)
println selected
```

Comment: Please add what resul you expect.

Comment: <CompoundEmployee>
 <id>130</id>
 <person>
  <birth_name>Name2</birth_name>
  <employment_information>
   <job_information>
    <custom_string13>MD_6_DAY</custom_string13>
    <custom_string14>MW_9R</custom_string14>
   </job_information>
   <job_information>
    <custom_string13>MD_6_DAY</custom_string13>
    <custom_string14>MW_9R</custom_string14>
   </job_information>
  </employment_information>
 </person>
</CompoundEmployee>

Comment: So it should pick only the second segment